# in php how can i generate dynamic id for each input textbox created in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how to get the selected textbox id generated in while loop for updating the field as in phpmyadmin

```
 <?php
    while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input type=text id='hello' name='hello' data-id="<?php echo  $fet['username']?>"     onchange='loadXMLDoc(this);' value=<?php echo $fet['username']?>>
       <td><input type=text id='uid' name='uid' onchange='loadXMLDoc(this).' value=<?php echo  $fet['id']?>>
       </tr>
       <?php 
        }
  ?>
```

Comment: i didn't understand your question  you want get the val of a multiple checkbox ? or generate a dinaimiq id in the php?

Comment: I want to generate dynamic id for textbox

Comment: heres  all the documentation about uniqid http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append i and increment it till your while loop goes on..

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    {
       echo '
        <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="hello'.$i.'" name="hello'.$i.'" data-id="'.$fet['username'].'" onchange="loadXMLDoc(this.value,'.$i.')" value='.$fet['username'].' >
</td>           
       </tr>';
       here write ur code for other fields

         $i++;
    }
 ?>

<script> 
function loadXMLDoc(a,i) 
{ var d= document.getElementById("hello"+i).value; } 
</script>
```

Comment: <script>

function loadXMLDoc(a)
{
 
 var d= document.getElementById(hello).value;
}  </script>how can i get that id here

Comment: if you want to take value from current text then use onchange='loadXMLDoc(this.value) it will return value of changing input text

Comment: have look @ my edited answer...u will come to know how to get exact field value too..

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use foreach as bellow way.**

```
foreach($sql1 as $value){

// don't generate html here

}
```

**Because it may brake the html**

Use foreach bellow way.

```
<?php

foreach($sql1 as $value):

?>

<tr>
 <td><input type=text id='hello' name='hello' data-id="<?php echo  $value['username']?>"    onchange='loadXMLDoc(this);' value=<?php echo $value['username']?>>
   <td><input type=text id='uid' name='uid' onchange='loadXMLDoc(this).' value=<?php echo  $value['id']?>>
</tr>

<?php endforeach() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `uniqid()` function
`$str=uniqid("uid")` it will make some thing like ti uid1hq7266
and print it in the input